# Command to show partition scheme

Tags: command-line, partitioning

What is the command for looking at the partition scheme of the hard disk on Ubuntu?

I know we can see the partition scheme in Gparted, but how can we run it on command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many possible ways. These three below should be the most common. The stuff after `#` on the command lines are comments explaining what each of them does, you don't need to copy them.

#### lsblk

This is probably the most simple tool to get a quick overview of what partitions exist. Nested structures (e.g. disk > partition > LUKS container > LVM container > volume) are also nicely displayed as a tree. Runs as regular user, no `sudo` needed.

You get (amongst others) information about device name, size, type and mount point (if mounted). With the option `-f` it will show file system type, label and UUID.

It's possible to specify a disk, partition or any similar device to only view information about that instead of listing everything.

Examples:

```bsh
lsblk                     # default info about all devices
lsblk -f                  # file system info about all devices
lsblk /dev/sda1           # default info about the /dev/sda1 partition and its children only
lsblk -f /dev/sdb         # file system info about the /dev/sdb disk and its children only
```

See `man lsblk` for more info.

#### parted

`parted` is a more powerful command-line tool, similar to its GUI pendant GParted. It can also modify the partitioning layout. Note that this requires elevated privileges (`sudo`) to run.

It will show you information about your disk hardware (model, type, size, sector size, ...) as well as a detailed partition table including start and end positions, size, type, file system, flags, label, ...

You can either list everything or specify a disk to print details about.

Examples:

```bsh
sudo parted -l                 # show info about all devices
sudo parted /dev/sda print     # show info about the /dev/sda disk only
```

See `man parted` for more info.

#### fdisk

`fdisk` is very similar to `parted`. It is also able to make modifications, requires elevated privileges and shows basically the same information as well.

Examples:

```bsh
sudo fdisk -l                  # show info about all devices
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda         # show info about the /dev/sda disk only
```

See `man fdisk` for more info.

Comment: `lsblk` requires `sudo` if you want certain info, like volume label and filesystem type.

Comment: @WJAndrea Are you sure? I can't confirm your statement on 16.04, for me both `lsblk` and `sudo lsblk` (or `lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -f`) show exactly the same amount of information.

Comment: Oh yeah, on 16.04 it's not required. I guess it changed since 14.04, which I'm using.

Answer (score 5):

## fdisk

For my two 1 TB disks

```
sudo fdisk -l # (ell)
```

gives the following output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x81fe91a0

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048     821247     819200   400M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2           821248 1953525167 1952703920 931,1G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5           823296  391028735  390205440 186,1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6        391030784 1415032831 1024002048 488,3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       1415034880 1451898879   36864000  17,6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x81fe91a0

Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048 1953523711 1953521664 931,5G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5            4096  629149695  629145600   300G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb6       629151744 1258297343  629145600   300G 83 Linux
```

---

## lsblk

The command

```
lsblk # apparently no sudo needed
```

gives

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   400M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0 186,1G  0 part /
├─sda6   8:6    0 488,3G  0 part /home
└─sda7   8:7    0  17,6G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0   300G  0 part /mnt/freeA
└─sdb6   8:22   0   300G  0 part /mnt/freeB
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

(`sr0` is a DVD drive).

Comment: Don't forget `gdisk`, the GPT-equivalent of `fdisk`!

Answer (score 0):

`lsblk` will list partitions and size and mount point.